# Extrinsic camera parameters from geo coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, camera, camera-calibration

I have gps.json and poses.json. I want to calculate extrinsic parameters with respect to geo coordinate in python.
From extrinsics.json I can compute rotation and translation matrix, but with respect to geo coordinate, I have no idea. Are these information enough for calculating?

gps.json:

{"lat": 37.466926769909506,     "long": -122.20860015120748, "height": 13.156501201630784, "xvel": 0.017909648835831914, "yvel": 7.057413955979734}

poses.json:

```
{

    "position": {

        "x": -0.3,

        "y": 0.36,

        "z": 1.82

    },

    "heading": {

        "w": 0.6,

        "x": -0.6,

        "y": -0.2,

        "z": 0.2

    }

}
```

How to calculate the extrinsic parameters from this information??